# Visual Studio comment and uncomment with a single simple keyboard shortcut

Tags: visual-studio, comments, keyboard-shortcuts

I want to know if it is possible to comment and uncomment text blocks in Visual Studio with a single command.

I'm used to just press **<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>/</kbd>** to toggle between comment and uncomment text blocks, because I've been using IntelliJ IDEA.

But in Visual Studio you have to press:
<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>k</kbd> + <kbd>c</kbd> to comment code, and
<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>k</kbd> + <kbd>u</kbd> to uncomment code.

Is there any way to comment / uncomment your code in Visual Studio with a single command just like in IntelliJ IDEA?

Answer (score 4):

Actually yes, there is a way.

- Go to `Tools` -> `Options...`  in the menu
- Select `Environment` -> `Keyboard` from the options list
- Find / Show `Edit.ToggleLineComment` in the keyboard commands list

[image: Options — Environment -> Keyboard — Edit.ToggleLineComment]

Here you can setup how to comment / uncomment a single or even multiple lines with a single keyboard shortcut.

Answer (score 2):

You can actually follow this path `Tools -> Options -> Environment -> Keyboard` and change the drop-down selection on your top right to `Visual Studio Code`. This will allow you to use the Visual Studio Code keyboard bindings such as CTRL+/ to comment/uncomment.