# How to customize Visual Studio 2022 keyboard shortcut for comment/uncomment with ctrl + /

Tags: visual-studio

This solution only works partially and only if you clear the prior assignment for Ctrl + /

[Visual Studio comment and uncomment with a single simple keyboard shortcut](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72541764/visual-studio-comment-and-uncomment-with-a-single-simple-keyboard-shortcut)

The prior assignment is:

```
EditorContextMenus.CodeWindow.GenerateDocumentationComments
```

I say "partially" because while it works with C, C++, C# and JS files, it does not work with Python, XAML or AXAML files.  I did not check other types, just these.